# NMAKE : fatal error U1077 while building OpenBR

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, cmake, openbr

I'm trying to build OpenBR, I followed the steps on http://openbiometrics.org/docs/install/#windows but I get stuck on this. The first time I used nmake, I got to 19%. Last week it worked on another computer
(thesame compiler, cmd, ...). It broke down now I have to rebuild it. I've been looking for over 15 hours now.

```
C:\openbr\build-msvc2013>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

[  2%] Built target models
[  3%] Automatic moc for target openbr
[  3%] Built target openbr_automoc
[  4%] Building CXX object openbr/CMakeFiles/openbr.dir/plugins/classification/cascade_classifier.cpp.obj
cascade_classifier.cpp
C:\openbr\openbr\plugins\classification\cascade_classifier.cpp(229) : error C2660: 'br::Classifier::train' : function does not take 1 arguments
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\bin\X86_AM~1\cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

This is the part where it goes wrong:

```
void train(const TemplateList &data)
{
        foreach (const Template &t, data)
            t.file.get<float>("Label") == 1.0f ? posImages.append(t) : negImages.append(t);

        qDebug() << "Total images:" << data.size()
                 << "\nTotal positive images:" << posImages.size()
                 << "\nTotal negative images:" << negImages.size();

        posIndices = Common::RandSample(posImages.size(), posImages.size(), true);
        negIndices = Common::RandSample(negImages.size(), negImages.size(), true);

        stages.reserve(numStages);
        for (int i = 0; i < numStages; i++) {
            qDebug() << "===== TRAINING" << i << "stage =====";
            qDebug() << "<BEGIN";

            Classifier *next_stage = Classifier::make(stageDescription, NULL);
            stages.append(next_stage);

            float currFAR = getSamples();

            if (currFAR < maxFAR && !requireAllStages) {
                qDebug() << "FAR is below required level! Terminating early";
                return;
            }

            stages.last()->train(posSamples + negSamples);

            qDebug() << "END>";
        }
    }
```

This is the whole file:
https://github.com/biometrics/openbr/blob/master/openbr/plugins/classification/cascade_classifier.cpp

Comment: Have you tried to debug? E.g., remove all code from the function except errorneos line.

Comment: I kinda gave up. The problem is that it is a library and when it's build it is over 1GB big. Since training Classifiers are the fundamentals in computer vision to recognise thing, I cannot possibly delete it. I'm gonna make an age estimation algorithm myself now.